# Finding particular solution to non-homogeneous DE: $y''-y'+\frac{1}{4}y = 3 + e^\frac{x}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the non-homogeneous differential equation:

$y''-y'+\frac{1}{4}y = 3 + e^\frac{x}{2}$

I'll start by finding the particular solution and this is where I get stuck. First I know I need to have $y_p = y_{p1} + y_{p2}$

Where  $y_{p1}$ will be in the form $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ and $y_{p2}$ will be in the form $De^{\frac{x}{2}}$

$y_{p2}$$' = \frac{1}{2}De^{\frac{x}{2}}$

$y_{p2}$$'' = \frac{1}{4}De^{\frac{x}{2}}$

Plugging this in to the differential equation above and solving for $e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ on the right hand side I get:

$\frac{1}{4}D - \frac{1}{2}D + \frac{1}{4}D = 1$

$0D = 1$?

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try 
$$y_p=Ax^2e^{(x/2)}+B$$
$$\implies B=12$$
You just need to plug $y_p=Ax^2e^{(x/2)}$ and find the constant $A$
Since you have that:
$$y_h=c_1e^{(x/2)}+c_2xe^{(x/2)}$$

Comment: normaly it should work with a factor of $x^2$ @bernard

Comment: No @Bernard I choose $y_p=Ax^2e^{(x/2)}$ and $A=1/2$ did you check the particular solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I had misread the r.h.s. as $\color{red}x\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac x2}$. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: No problem @Bernard

Comment: I got $A = 0$. Is that correct?

Comment: no @AndrewKor  $A=1/2$

Comment: Well I'm very confused. I set $y_{p1} = Ax^2e^{x/2}$. Next I differentiate to get prime and double prime of this. Then substitute into the DE and set it equal to $x^2e^{x/2}$. LHS becomes just "2A" so since $2A = 0$, then $A = 0.$ Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you are close  @AndrewKor   ....Because $$2Ae^\frac{x}{2}=e^\frac{x}{2} \implies A=1/2$$ you are solving the inhomogeneous equation and not  the homogeneous one

Comment: I don't get it. I have $2Ae^{\frac{x}{2}} = x^2e^{\frac{x}{2}}+ xe^{\frac{x}{2}} + e^{\frac{x}{2}}$..

Comment: @AndrewKor  you are really close . Note that on the right side of the equation you dont have $x^2$,but $e^\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Because since we're multiplying $2Ae^{\frac{x}{2}}$ by 1, we need to set it equal to the variable with the same coefficient? If we had let's say $2Axe^{\frac{x}{2}}$, we would set this equal to $xe^{\frac{x}{2}}$ and solve for $A$. I think I understand now. Thank you for your help

Comment: you are left with $2Ae^\frac{x}{2}$ on the left side and $e^\frac{x}{2} $ on the right side  @AndrewKor  you deduce that $A=1/2$

Answer (score 0):

No. By superposition of solutions, you need a solution for $\;y''-y'+\frac14y=3$ and a solution for  $\;y''-y'+\frac14y=x\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac x2}$.

- For  $\;y''-y'+\frac14y=3$, as $0$ is not a root of the characteristic equation, you can try $y_{p_1}=\text{constant}$.
- For  $\;y''-y'+\frac14y=x\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac x2}$, $\frac12$ *is* a *double* root of the characteristic equation, so you try
  $$y_{p_2}=(ax^3+bx^2+cx)\mathrm e^{\tfrac x2}$$

*Other method* (for $f_{p_2}$): *variation of constants*.

Setting $f_{p_2}=u\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac x2}$, where $u$ is twice differentiable, you'll obtain after simplification a differential equation for $u$.

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the constant using $y=12+u$ which makes
$$u''-u'+\frac{1}{4}u=  e^\frac{x}{2}$$ Now, make $u=v\,e^\frac{x}{2}$ to make 
$$v''=1$$ which seems to be simple.